# Linux server is out of space and unable to execute and command

Tags: linux, disk

I am login to the Linux terminal and the disk space got full. Now I am not unable to execute any command and any other user is not able to login on the server. What can be done in this case?

Comment: When I ran out of space on linux server I was always able to login and to run commands. Basically all you need is `ls` and `rm` to make some space. Maybe graphics login is not possible. Try login to tty (https://askubuntu.com/questions/467912/how-do-i-log-in-in-tty1).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please expand your question with more information on the specific operating system and error/log messages you encounter to make it easier for contributors to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't executing any commands on terminal. You can try:

1. Boot from liveCD (usb), to free disk space on local machine.
2. Boot into Recovery mode from grub.